# Parameter passing between two views

Tags: objective-c, view, xcode4, parameters

I use a first view (a class) where there is a button that shows me one second view (another class).
display looks like this:

```
listContactsViewController viewController * = [[listContactsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController * vc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewController];
[self presentModalViewController: vc animated: YES];
```

Then in the second view, I select the rows and then I have an "add" button that  to display the first view as this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

My problem is that in the second view I have an NSMutableArray that I would like to send to the first view.

If you have an idea.

Thank you.

Comment: try to define a `@property` in your second class and pass it after you init your new class like `[myClass setMyPorperty:parameterWhatIWantToPass]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to solve this.

Quick: in your second view controller

```
listContactsViewController
```

define a `delegate` property which holds a reference to the presenting controller (the one where you would like to use the NSArray created in `listContactsViewController`. Then, before dismissing the view controller, call a method in the `delegate` interface so that your presenting controller can get a copy of the array.

This is just a quick solution to your problem, though, not the best one.

A more correct solution would be to create a "model" object that is accessible from any controller in your app (a singleton would do) that holds the relevant data: `listContactsViewController` stores the array into the model; the presenting controller gets it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Delegates and Protocol.**

Refer this tutorial : [Passing data between views tutorial – using a protocol & delegate in your iPhone app.](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/)